# Unable to share files from on-prem OneDrive

Tags: 2016

We've upgraded from SP2013 to SP2016 and when users try to share a file from OneDrive, it sends an email to the user that the file is shared with them but it doesn't change the permissions on the file.

An example here is to click the *Only you* link
[image: only you link]

Share with another user
[image: Share with another user]

It confirms the file was shared

[image: Share confirmation]

Refreshing the page still shows *Only me* listed as access and the user cannot access the file.

[image: Access not granted]

I found the entries in the ULS when sharing a file, but it shows a number of exceptions for missing OOTB fields within the entries with the same correlation id.

```
Unable to locate the xml-definition for FieldName with FieldId '<GUID>'
```

I looked up the guids and they are all standard fields

```
Guid                                    Field
-----                                   -----
65572d4d-445a-43f1-9c77-3358222a2c93    FormCategory
467e811f-0c12-4a93-bb04-42ff0c1c597b    TemplateId
467e811f-0c12-4a93-bb04-42ff0c1c597c    FormRelativeUrl
1fff255c-6c88-4a76-957b-ae24bf07b78c    FormDescription
1a03fa74-8c63-40cc-bd06-73b580bd8743    LinkTemplateName
1a03fa74-8c63-40cc-bd06-73b580bd8744    FormId
94ad6f7c-09a1-42ca-974f-d24e080160c2    FormVersion
58eb8694-8bd6-4f98-8097-374bd97ffec4    CustomContentTypeId
96c27c9d-33f5-4f8e-893e-684014bc7090    FormLocale
4ef69ca4-4179-4d27-9e6c-f9544d45dfdc    ShowInCatalog
66b691cf-07a3-4ca6-ac6d-27fa969c8569    FormName
```

After all of these exceptions, it appears to skip sharing

```
SPSharedWithHelper.AddPrincipalsToSharedWithField: Skipping updating the 'SharedWith' column for list item 'Documents/YEEHAAW.docx' under site 'https://mysite.example.com/my/userName'. SPPrincipleType='User'. UserCollectionContainsPrincipal='True'.
```

Does anyone know what to do to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like you're using the classic ODfB interface -- any reason you don't set it to the modern ODfB interface? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/configure-the-onedrive-for-business-modern-user-experience

Comment: @TrevorSeward Never came across that option until you linked it. Additionally enabling "version 2" fixes the sharing issues too. If you leave an answer for this, I'll accept it.

Comment: Awesome, glad it fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to using the OneDrive for Business [modern interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/configure-the-onedrive-for-business-modern-user-experience) in SharePoint 2016.